# Proof of financial stability for Portugal

Tags: indian-citizens, paperwork, schengen-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

For the sake of the question, I am Indian.

My trip to Schengen (Portugal and France) is sponsored by my father. I have submitted a scanned letter from him that he will sponsor my travel, enclosing his bank details, etc. But at some links online I got to know that an original affidavit is required from my dad but I didnt submit it along with my visa application. How will it affect the visa approval chances?

Comment: Where have you seen this requirement stated?

Comment: http://pt.vfsglobal.co.in/pdf/TOURIST-VISA.pdf

point 10

Answer (score 1):

According to the VFS checklist http://pt.vfsglobal.co.in/pdf/TOURIST-VISA.pdf a notarized Sponsorship Letter is REQUIRED.

10
Sponsorship Proof:
If the applicant is sponsored by another person, an original Sponsorship Letter is required on Rs. 100 Stamp Paper and must be Notarized. If the Sponsor is in not in India, the Sponsorship Letter should be Notarized/Attested by a Notary/Advocate if in the E.U. or from the respective Portugal Consulate/Embassy in other countries.

As it states at the bottom of the checklist, failure to submit a required document may result in a refusal. Sponsorship proof is a critical element of demonstrating sufficient funds; without it, your chance of approval is likely to be much reduced. The Consulate may ask you for it, or they may just decide to refuse. You should get the Letter and contact them to find out how you can correct the error.